# How to show that level curves of a function are bounded?

Tags: functions, optimization

I am working through a textbook and one of the questions asked to plot a function and its level curves. The follow-up question was, "Show the level curves of the function are bounded". I have plotted the function and its level curves, but I am not sure how one shows that they are bounded. Frankly, I am not sure what it means to say that the level curves are bounded in the first place. Tried to google around but to no avail. Could anyone share any insight into this? Thank you.

The function given is  $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad f(x,y) = (y-\cos x)^2 + (y-x)^2$

Comment: If your function is $f$ then the level curve at level $\alpha$ is the set $\mathrm{Lev}_{\alpha}(f) := \{ x \mid f(x) = \alpha \}$ (all the points that $f$ maps to $\alpha$). So you need to show that this set is bounded.

Comment: Hi thank you. I've edited the question to include the function. Would I be correct in saying that one approach would be to substitute very large values for $x$ and $y$, showing that the level sets are bounded  by $y^2$?

Comment: Here the point is that $\cos(x)\in [-1;1]$, hence if $y$ is large, also $$f(x,y)\geq (y-\cos(x))^2$$ will be large (in particular larger than $\alpha$ and therefore notvon the level curve). Thus, the $y$ components of the level curve are bounded, i.e. $y\in [-C;C]$. Now play the same game with $(x-y)^2$ to see that the $x-$component of the points on the level curve is bounded too

Comment: Hi @SeverinSchraven , thanks for the reply! What you said about $\cos x$ makes a lot of sense, although I am confused about something. Could you clarify why $y$ being large implies that $f(x,y)$ is larger than $\alpha$? Thank you!

Comment: @ClassicBeavs: Notice that $f(x, y) \geq (y - \cos(x))^2 \geq y^2 - 2 y$. If you make $y$ large enough (say $y = 10 \max(\alpha, 1)$), you can see the desired inequality.

Comment: @VHarisop: thank you for the reply! Sorry, I'm still a bit confused, what is the significance of $y^2 - 2y$ here? Does this come from an expansion of the second term?

Comment: @ClassicBeavs: It's a lower bound on the first term (by opening up the square) for positive $y$. The second term is always nonnegative so can be safely discarded when examining the effect of large $y$.

Comment: @VHarisop: Thanks, it makes sense now! In the case of large $x$, can we just expand the terms to see that $f(x,y)$ is always $\geq x$ ?

Comment: Yes, I think you could show this (not sure about $\geq x$, but I can definitely see the case $\geq c x$ for some constant $c \geq 0$).